# Sqlmapapi configuring task options

Tags: api, vulnerability-scanners, sqlmap

I'm trying to make scans using [Sqlmapapi](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/blob/master/sqlmapapi.py). I have added a new task, and when I call `/option/$taskId/list` in response, I receive JSON output with options that can be set.

I could not find any information on how can I do it. How to call API to set a cookie header, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `"cookie": "cookie value"` to JSON, which You create while calling to scan/$taskID/start